# django-dynamic-formset shows "add" and "remove" buttons in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, django, inline-formset

My app was working fine yesterday.  After I started playing with the .css properties in the browser , suddenly the django-dynamic-formset script is not working properly anymore.  It shows "Add" and "Remove" buttons for each input in the form, instead of for each row.  Please see the photo attached.

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

<table>
{{ formset.management_form|crispy }}

    {% for form in formset.forms %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <td>
                    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{ hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}

                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}

</table>

<!-- <p class='btn btn-warning' id='agregar'>Agregar Posición</p> -->
<br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
{{formset.media}}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dynamic_formsets/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/static/collected/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#agregar').on('click',function(){
    $('.formset-test').append()
  });
</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar posición',
        deleteText: 'Borrar posición',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
</script>`
```

Also, its not respecting the renaming I gave (see script at the end of the code).  Instead of the "Agregar Posicion" text, shows the default one which is "Add another".

Answer (score 0):

You have got a few different issues going on:

First, you are calling the .formset function directly on a jQuery object.  Per [the docs](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst), it needs to be wrapped in an "on-ready" function, like this, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar posición',
        deleteText: 'Borrar posición',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
})
</script>
```

This should solve the issue with the custom parameters not being used, as they weren't passed to the .formset function.

As for the adding the tag to each input, you didn't supply your views.py or forms.py files to know what you are actually passing to the template, but from my experience working with the django-dynamic-formset plugin, it's persnickety.  I have found that using the class name selector works best if you're working with divs in forms, but the example from the docs using tables works best with tables. If you assign your table an "id" and then added a tbody tag, you would change the code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#your-table-id tbody tr').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar posición',
        deleteText: 'Borrar posición',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
})
</script>
```

Also, without seeing your views.py file, but I'm not sure why you're using

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
```

You should just be passing the formset from your view to your template and referencing it as

```
{% for form in formset %}
```